# Custom Cache Implementation in Ignite

Tags: caching, ignite

I had a small query over Apache Ignite. Can we have a custom implementation of cache in to store the in-memory state? & where can we plugin the custom implementation.

For eg,

Currently, by default we have IgniteCache for cache management. Can we have something like MyCache for management of cache with the method signatures being the same just the storage technique being different?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by storage technique? What exactly are trying to achieve? What is the business use case for this?

Comment: Hi Valentin, I wanted to use a different data structure with to store data. for example, it can be a customized implementation of Map / javax.cache.Cache interface with all operations like put, getValue and other operations.

Comment: I want to define a custom Durable Memory Layer(https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs) and use the other layers as is

Comment: This sounds like rewriting 80% of Ignite :) I doubt it makes sense and I still don't understand why you want to do this. Data storage is the main thing Ignite provides and if it doesn't satisfy your needs for some reason, probably it makes to look for something else.

Comment: Have you considered using Ignite service grid? You will be able to provide your own service API and utilize all Ignite features inside of the implementation. More information here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/service-example